# id from url is shown undefined when used privateroute inside route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I need to show components related to guides in both public and private mode. I mean list of guides, create guides, guide detail should be able to view by anyone but edit guide page should be accessible to only authenticated guide. For this I tried the following way

In main component

App.js

```
<Route path="/guides" component={Guides} />
```

And inside Guides.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        exact
        path={`${GUIDE_ROUTES.GUIDE_DEF}`}
        component={ListGuides}
    />
    <Route path={`${GUIDE_ROUTES.ADD_GUIDE}`} component={GuideForm} />
    <PrivateRoute
        path={`${GUIDE_ROUTES.EDIT_GUIDE}`}
        component={GuideForm}
    />
    <Route path={`${GUIDE_ROUTES.DETAIL_GUIDE}`} component={GuideDetail} />
</Switch>
```

The url are in this format

```
const GUIDE_DEF = "/guides";

export const GUIDE_ROUTES = {
  GUIDE_DEF,
  ADD_GUIDE: `${GUIDE_DEF}/new`,
  EDIT_GUIDE: `${GUIDE_DEF}/edit/:guideId`,
  DETAIL_GUIDE: `${GUIDE_DEF}/:guideId`,
};
```

When using `<PrivateRoute path={`${GUIDE_ROUTES.EDIT_GUIDE}`} component={GuideForm} />` I cannot get `guideId`. It gives me undefined. But if I used `<PrivateRoute path="/guides" component={Guides} />` in App.js then it works perfectly. But I don't want overall guides section to be private only the things like edit part, payment part should be private.

Here is my code for PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {
  const renderContent = props => {
    console.log("PROPS", props, rest);
    if (!isLogin()) {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/auth/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      );
    }

    return typeof render === "function" ? (
      render(props)
    ) : (
      <Component {...props} {...rest} />
    );
  };
  return <Route render={renderContent} />;
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element])
    .isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.object,
  render: PropTypes.func
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Can anyone help me at this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GuideForm` you can access `guideId` with

```
props.computedMatch.params.guideId
```

Or change privet route to return like below.(pass `...rest` to Route)

```
<Route {...rest} render={renderContent} />
```

Comment: why do i need to use computedMatch when I use PrivateRoute for it? Can you please make me clear on this?

Comment: Because you didn't pass `...rest` to the final route.Good luck.